# using parseInt on an input field doesnot work

Tags: javascript, parseint, typeof

```
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num-one").value) ; //'num-one , num-two'is an <input> text field
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num-two").value) ;
var test = num1 + num2 ;
```

so when i open Devtools and type in the console :

```
typeof test
>'number'
```

but when I log it :

```
console.log(test)
>NaN
```

why ?

Comment: the problem is with `(document.getElementById("num-one").value` , it is `undefined` or `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test out

`typeof NaN`

In the browser console, you'll notice it returns `"number."`

Looks like one of the inputs you're trying to parseInt with is probably `undefined` or `null` as both of those would return `NaN`

Here's a resource to explain why `NaN` is typeof number

https://javascriptrefined.io/nan-and-typeof-36cd6e2a4e43#.xzui6g25g

Comment: thanks , but the inputs I am trying to parseInt  are strings

Comment: I mean `typeof document.getElementById("num-one").value >string`

Comment: even when the input is a number the value remains a string after parsing

Comment: because if the input is empty its value is "" and the typeof that is string. parseInt("") is NaN